# Razor.ServiceStack - Views not rendering, just default "Snapshot"

Tags: razor, mono, nginx, servicestack

I've setup a site using http://razor.servicestack.net/.

I've created several views and matching services with an example as follows:

Service Example:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace website
{
    [DefaultView("AboutUs")]
    public class AboutUsService : Service
    {
        public object Get(AboutUsRequest request)
        {
            return new AboutUsResponse
            {
                //any properties that need to be set on the response object can be done inline here
            };
        }     
    }

    [Route("/About-Us")]
    public class AboutUsRequest
    {
        //any request parameters we need can be provided here.  They should be auto parsed from the request
    }

    public class AboutUsResponse
    {
        //any response properties we want to use in the view can be defined here     
    }

}
```

View Example (located at /Views/AboutUs.cshtml)

```
 @inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<website.AboutUsResponse>
 <html><body><h1>About Us</h1></body></html>
```

This loads fine on windows, but fails to load on Mono/NginxFastCGI, and instead just shows the default API snapshot page:

```
Snapshot of AboutUsRequest generated by ServiceStack on 11/17/2012 02:30:14
view json datasource from original url: http://dev.mydomain.com:80/About-Us? in other formats: json xml csv jsv
```

Is there some specific change that I need to configure for this to work on the Mono/Linux side?  By the way, i have IOMAP=all already turned on.

Any ideas on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you left out the most important part: the name and location of the Razor view.

The Snaphot page is a fallback for when ServiceStack can't find the view it's looking for, in this case since you've specified [DefaultView("AboutUs")], ServiceStack will look for a view named "AboutUs.cshtml" in the /Views/ directory, is that what you have?

Comment: mythz, thanks for taking a look.  Yes, i have updated the question with the path to the view, which is:  /Views/AboutUs.cshtml

Comment: It looks like IOMAP is what was causing the issue, however this works fine on MVC3 for me.  Can you explain why IOMAP is causing the issues?  Thanks!

Comment: No idea, Didn't even know what IOMAP was until I just looked it up. Tho ServiceStack includes its own path normalizing functionality, so you shouldn't need IOMAP enabled.

Comment: I think it would be a good thing to look further into, and put a note on the razor.servicestack website about disabling MONO_IOMAP (http://mono-project.com/IOMap) if you're having issues with views not being found when using servicestack.  I just confirmed that setting MONO_IOMAP=all and allowing that variable in the ALLOWED_ENV list (I use spawn-fcgi) was indeed the issue, but re-enabling it for a test.

Comment: I'm semi-new to stackoverflow, so not sure how to handle this, but I'm going to give you credit for the answer since your reply lead me to the answer.  Cheers.  :)