# ServiceStack not rendering Razor Views. Just seeing Snapshot. Config wrong?

Tags: razor, servicestack

Note: This question while similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427225/razor-servicestack-views-not-rendering-just-default-snapshot?rq=1) however it's about different issues.

It seems for whatever reason ServiceStack is not running/compiling Razor views and seems like a config issue however RazorRockstarts runs fine.

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.11 and have compared against RazorRockstars runnning ServiceStack 4.0.8

1. In VS2013 I have created a new ASP.NET Website (Empty)
2. Install-Package ServiceStack
3. Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor
4. Added httpHandlers to web.config
5. Created AppHost and .Init() in Global.asax Application_Start.
6. AppHost.LoadPlugin(new RazorFormat());
7. Created /Services/HomeService.cs (inherited from ServiceStack.Service)
8. Created Home route in HomeService
9. Created /Views/Home/Home.cshtml

I run in debug on VS 2013 and all I get is the ServiceStack snapshot when going to `/home`. What am I missing?

`/AppHost.cs`

```
using Funq;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Razor;
namespace SSTest
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("SSTest", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            LoadPlugin(new RazorFormat());
        }
        public static void Start()
        {
            new AppHost().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

`/Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppHost.Start();
}
```

`/Services/HomeService.cs`

```
using ServiceStack;
namespace SSTest.Services
{
    [Route("/home")]
    public class Home
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [DefaultView("Home")]
    public class HomeServices : Service
    {
        public object Get(Home request)
        {
            return new Home(){Name = "Here's home!"};
        }   
    }
}
```

`/Views/Home/Home.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>This is home!!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`/Web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="SSTest" />
        <add namespace="SSTest.Services" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Note: inside Configure() Plugins should be loaded with: `Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());`. Do you have a `Views\_Layout.cshtml`? because Layout = null, suggests to use the default layout template, whilst Layout="" suggests to use none.

Comment: In Configure(), what is the difference between `LoadPlugin()` and `Plugins.Add()`? `Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat())` seems to throw a `HttpCompileException` saying it requires `OrmLite` however I'm not using OrmLite in this test project. I did `Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite` and ran the project and it works now. Not sure why `OrmLite` is required for Razor views.

Comment: I would hunt down that error (dirty dlls?) before trying an alternative configuration that's not documented anywhere. RazorFormat doesn't even reference OrmLite so its masking a different error. Plugins in Configure are delay loaded after required initialization is done, whilst LoadPlugin attempts to load the plugin then and there, which is not right when inside Configure().

Comment: Hmmm... I just setup this clean project (steps mentioned above) to test Razor views in ServiceStack. No DB calls or anything in this test project other than a single Razor view and service. There is no other code in this project that I've done except listed above in the question. Which is why I'm confused why it said error. `System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OrmLite' does not exist in the namespace 'ServiceStack' (are you missing an assembly reference?) at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.CreateRazorPageInstance`...

Comment: OK then you want to remove "ServiceStack.OrmLite" from the Razor Namespaces in your Web.Config since it's not in your project.

Comment: Good call. Works now. Did NuGet add that reference? I'm fairly sure I didn't add it. Update: Yeah `Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor` puts `<add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />` into the web.config.

Comment: Yeah it's a common configuration to have since OrmLite's extension methods which makes the `base.Db` ADO.NET IDbConnection much more useful than on its own. Looks like the dependencies need updating to prevent errors with this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Configure()` plugins should be loaded with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
```

In ServiceStack.Razor `Layout = null`, suggests to use the default layout template `Views\_Layout.cshtml`, you can choose not use any template with `Layout=""` instead.

If you don't have OrmLite installed then you want to remove the **ServiceStack.OrmLite** namespace from being included in all Razor pages by removing it from your **Web.config**:

```
<add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you had any suggestions on how to debug why a particular cshtml view isn't found or doesn't qualify to be returned. Is there, for example, something like a log, or are we able to force SS to return only a cshtml view and see the resulting error?

Comment: God yes.  I love ServiceStack, but I've spent ~8 hours now trying to get one simple Razor-based site working with it.  VERY frustrating without a clue what I'm doing wrong!!!

Comment: Note to my future self:  Make sure there aren't any errors in your layout page.  *facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

I know mythz has solved your problem, but something else to check for future readers with the same problem:

Make sure your `*.cshtml` files are copied to the output directory. For whatever reason, mine weren't, thus ServiceStack couldn't find them and all I got was the snapshot like yourself.

I'm not sure if this is related to using a self-hosted console application instead of a web project.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be located in `/Views/Home.cshtml` instead of `/Views/Home/Home.cshtml`.

Comment: I've tried moving it there as well. It doesn't work with the cshtml in any location. Note: In the working RazorRockstars I created a "/Views/Rockstars/" directory and placed the "Rockstars.cshtml" in that directory (/Views/Rockstars/Rockstars.cshtml) and Rockstars still runs correctly so I don't think that is the issue. I've also successfully used View subdirectories with ServiceStace v3. I'm thinking it is some config issue that I'm missing. Not sure what though.

Comment: Also, I've created a default.cshtml in the root and that doesn't work as well. No razor page seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue!  With the current **ServiceStack VS template** (as of April 1, 2015 and no this isn't an April Fools joke!), the following line will mess things up *if you're running a self-hosted service*:

```
WebHostPhysicalPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("~".MapServerPath(), "..", "..")),
```

This is within your `AppHost.cs` file inside of the `Configure(Container)` function within the `SetConfig(new HostConfig { /* ... here ... */ } );` block.

Comment out the entire `WebHostPhysicalPath = ...` line and re-run your application.

A better fix than simply commenting it out is to set the correct directory which is either your actual bin directory via:

```
WebHostPhysicalPath = Path.GetFullPath("~".MapServerPath()),
```

Or, if you have a specific build architecture (ie. x86 or x64 instead of AnyCPU), you likely have a third layer of folders.  So change the WebHostPhysicalPath to this:

```
WebHostPhysicalPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("~".MapServerPath(), "..", "..", "..")),
```